# Most efficient way to reorder an array of objects with a number value?

Tags: javascript

Say I have this array:

```
let array = [
   {
      id: 81487y9184,
      order: 0
   },
   {
      id: 87dsg87y23,
      order: 1
   },
   ...
]
```

Now if I remove the object with order 1 from the array, how would I best be able to go through the array and move all orders over 1, down one?

Comment: Where is this data coming from?  Is the `order` value even needed?  You could just use its position/index in the array.

Comment: Speaking of which, if you _do_ need the `order`, then you can just loop over the array and set the `order` of the object to its index in the array.

Comment: wouldn't you simply sort by "order"?

Comment: @Rick I _think_ the array is already sorted by `order`, and the OP wants to remove one object and _edit_ the other other objects to reflect their new array positions.

Comment: Seems to just make this array inefficient. Please explain why you need `order` anyway. You know there is `array.indexOf(object)`?

Comment: @trincot `indexOf` doesn't work with with objects.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, sure it does: `array.indexOf(array[5])` will return 5.

Comment: @trincot But you already know the index, it's 5.  It doesn't work with stuff like `array.indexOf({id: '81487y9184', order: 0})` since the comparing objects in JavaScript checks to see if they are the _same_ object (pointer to memory) not the same values.

Comment: @trincot I have an array stored in React Native that I am removing the object from that holds the order. Upon this removal, I need to update the change of order on the DB side. The indexOf won't work unless I change the order of the array on the DB side each removal. I figured storing the order in an object value would be more practical. Maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: @RocketHazmat, it is not relevant that I knew the index - it was just a quick demo that if I *have the object* and `array`, I can use `indexOf`. If you have access to the `order` property, it means you have access to the object that is sitting in the array. So it is the same thing.

Comment: @RocketHazmat presumably if you have an array of objects, you assign them to stuff and then still have the same object. You can use that to look up its position in the array it came from.

Comment: @trincot Fair enough, if you already have a reference to the object, then I guess it would work :)

Comment: @user3088464, please explain why you need the `order` information stored in the DB as a sequential number starting at 0. It smells like a wrong design. Why do you need such a number *at all*?

Comment: @trincot Look at my comment above

Comment: I replied to that comment... it doesn't answer why you really *need* it. You write *" I need to update the change of order on the DB side."*. But that doesn't explain *why*... Databases are designed to be strong on keeping things ordered after removal and insertion, using indexes. It is their speciality. Why don't you rely on that?

Comment: The user can upload images and rearrange their order. To handle the change of the order of how the images in their user profile should appear, I thought storing that in DB would be a good move?

Comment: It is a bad move if you have to update 50% of all records on average.

Comment: So your recommendation is to change the array order on the DB side of things and have the frontend read from it that way? I'm talking about the index

Comment: No, my advice is to use a numbering system with big gaps in the numbering (like steps of 1000). If user reorders, calculate the middle between the predecessor and the successor's order, and only update the current record with that new number. If ever there is no more free integer (because predecessor and successor have 1 difference in order), then do a complete table update, introducing again the gaps of 1000. But that would be a rare event, and could also be done as a job over night.

Answer (score 2):

The following code will find the item with `order: 1` and decrement the following orders using a `for` loop:

```
const index = array.findIndex((item) => item.order === 1);
if (index >= 0) {
  array.splice(index, 1); // delete array[index]
  for (let i = index; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i].order--;  // or array[i].order = i
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

simple way to do it would be

```
array.forEach(function(item, index) {
  item.order = index;
});
```

Comment: `forEach` gives a second argument, so `array.forEach(function(item, index) { item.order = index; });` would be more concise and maybe clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove object with order 1 from array:

```
const index = array.findIndex((item) => item.order === 1);
array.splice(index, 1);
```

Reordering:

```
array.sort((a,b) => a.order - b.order).map((e,i) => e.order = i);
```

Get the result:

```
console.log(array);
```